# Tailwind CSS - Vertically space between items

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have been trying to use content-between using Tailwind CSS to distribute rows in a container so that there is equal space between each line. Please help.

```html
<div className="w-96 mx-10">
  <div className="flex flex-col content-between">
    <div className="bg-red-400">
      <h2 className="text-3xl">Technology Used</h2>
    </div>
    <div className="text-lg bg-blue-200">
      <ul>
        <li>ITEM1</li>
        <li>ITEM2</li>
        <li>ITEM3</li>
        <li>ITEM4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div className="bg-green-100">{project.description}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ` <div className="flex flex-col content-between">` should it be ` <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1">` ? Here's the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

To distribute your items in a flex container with equal space between them, **use [`justify-between`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/justify-content#space-between)**.

> *Note:* I added a height of `h-64` to your flex container, or else it will never be bigger than the sum of your items heights and thus, never spread them with space in between.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script></head>
<body>
    <div class="w-96 mx-10">
        <div class="flex flex-col justify-between h-64">
          <div class="bg-red-400">
            <h2 class="text-3xl">Technology Used</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="text-lg bg-blue-200">
            <ul>
              <li>ITEM1</li>
              <li>ITEM2</li>
              <li>ITEM3</li>
              <li>ITEM4</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="bg-green-100">{project.description}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you don't care about the items being distributed across the whole container, but just about them having equal space, you can also go with the following options:

- set [`space`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space) on your container to control the space between child elements
- set [`gap`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) on your container to control the gap between child elements (same as space in this single-row case, but [it can handle a lot more complex cases](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#limitations)) (specifically `gap-y` when you have `flex-col`)
- set the same [`margin`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin) top on each child item, but the first, e.g. `mt-4` ([`space` does just that under the hood](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#limitations))

### Explanation

**`content-between` is useless in your case.** In the Tailwind CSS docs it is listed under "[Align Content: Utilities **for controlling how rows are positioned in multi-row flex** and grid containers.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content)"

The problem here is, **this utility class is only for multi-row** flex and grid containers. **You got a single-row** flex container.

It's a bit counter-intuitive at first, because you need to accept the notion that *"row" means "line" here (it doesn't need to be horizontal, it can also be vertical!)*.

Think about it this way:

- "Do your items lie in one (!) (horizontal or vertical) line?"
- "Is your list linear (not a 2D array)?"

If the answer is yes, you got a "single-row flex".

##### multi-row container example

This container has 3 rows with 2 items each. The [`content-between`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content#space-between) distributes the rows such that there is an equal amount of space between each row.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script></head>
<body>
    <div class="p-2 text-white font-bold">
        <div class="h-44 grid grid-cols-2 content-between gap-2 text-center">
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">row 1</div>
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">row 1</div>
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">row 2</div>
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">row 2</div>
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">row 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

##### single-row container example

This container has a single "row" with 3 items (like your code).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script></head>
<body>
    <div class="p-2 text-white font-bold">
        <div class="h-44 flex flex-col text-center gap-2">
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">item 1</div>
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">item 2</div>
            <div class="p-1 rounded-lg bg-violet-500">item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below the code. This might work. use gap for equal spaces.

```
 <div className="w-96 mx-10">
          <div className="flex flex-col content-between gap-4">
            <div className="bg-red-400">
              <h2 className="text-3xl">Technology Used</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="text-lg bg-blue-200">
              <ul>
                <li>ITEM1</li>
                <li>ITEM2</li>
                <li>ITEM3</li>
                <li>ITEM4</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-green-100">{project.description}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You need to add `space-y-2` class in the parent element like the below code.

Reference link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space

```
<div className="flex flex-col content-between space-y-2">
  <div className="bg-red-400">
    <h2 className="text-3xl">Technology Used</h2>
  </div>
  <div className="text-lg bg-blue-200">
    <ul>
      <li>ITEM1</li>
      <li>ITEM2</li>
      <li>ITEM3</li>
      <li>ITEM4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div className="bg-green-100">{project.description}</div>
</div>
```